# Convert Sentence array into words in batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I have a sentence with words separated by an underscore say

```
sentence = matt_george_phil
```

I want to convert the names mentioned in this sentence in an array i.e.

```
arr[0] = matt
arr[1] = george
arr[2] = phil
```

I am new to batch Scripting. Can someone please tell how to do it. Thanks.

I have tried something like

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo run

set sentence=a~b~c

set /a i=0

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=~" %%a in ("%sentence%") do (
   set /a i+=1
   set array[!i!]=%%a
)

echo %array[1]%
echo %array[2]%
```

But there seems to be some problem with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

BAT language does not have the notion of arrays. You might however mimic it with various techniques.

One such technique is making use of the automatic parsing of parameters passed in a CALL command.

read HELP SET and HELP CALL and try this...

```
SET sentence=matt_george_phil
SET sentence=%sentence:_=%
CALL :asarray %sentence%
goto :eof

:asarray
echo first element = %1
echo second element = %2
echo third element = %3
```

Comment: I have added the code i just tried. Can you help me debug it.